# How to get data from google analytics in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

My API has the following endpoint: `my-api/v1/books/book/{id}`.

The "books" are serialized books on the web, each book has a category on my website.
The endpoint above has the parameter `?info=views`, to see the total views for the book that has the ID passed in the URL.

And here the problem begins. I found almost no information on the internet about how to use Google Analytics with Spring Boot, most of the tutorials are old and outdated. I know there is a Google Analytics Client library for Java, but there are no recent tutorials teaching how to use it.

This is the flow of what I want to do: 
1 - The user makes the request:
`my-api/v1/books/book/{id}?info=views` 
2 - The PathVariable ID is passed to my BookService. 
3 - In BookService, the book search is done. If the book is found, it must pass the "slug", the parent slug of a book would be something like `"my-book-01"`, the slugs have variations: `"my-book-01-chapter-02"`, each chapter of a book has a slug that identifies which book it belongs to.

```java
@Autowired
AnalyticsService analyticsService;

@Autowired 
BookRepository bookRepository;

// Other methods...//
@Override
public Long getViews(Long id)
{

   Optional<Book> optionalBook = bookRepository.findById(id);
   if(optionalBook.isPresent())
   {
      Book foundBook = optionalBook.get();
      Long totalViews = analyticsService.receiveDataFromAnalytics(foundBook.getSlug());  

      // logic to validate the views..... //

      return totalViews;
   } 
   //rest of the code...//
}
```

The "AnalyticsService" class does not exist in my code yet, what I want to know is what would be the structure of the request to be made in the `receiveDataFromAnalytics` method? 
I'd appreciate it if someone has an updated tutorial that can help me.

I have tried to follow YouTube tutorials, but they are all obsolete.